# SSIS won't download data to Excel Spreadsheet

Tags: ssis

I have data being downloaded to 2 different tabs in an excel spreadsheet from SSIS.  The first tab gets data, I see the data I want in the 2nd tab in the data viewer but when I retrieve the spreadsheet only the data in the 1st tab is there, only the column headers are in the second tab.  I am using the same connection manager for both of the spreadsheet tabs. Also, I am selecting the correct spreadsheet in the Excel Destination Editor. I am using a Multicast to the 2 excel destinations, the only difference is the destination for the 2nd tab has a derived column to add a coloumn and the aggregate function to group and total columns.

Comment: Welcome to Super User! It looks like you have created a second account, which will also interfere with your ability to comment within your thread, edit your posts, and accept your own answer.  See [Merge my accounts](http://superuser.com/help/merging-accounts) to get your accounts merged, which will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this problem by not renaming sheet 2 of the spreadsheet, when I renamed Sheet 2 of the spreadsheet to 'Counts' data would not appear in the spreadsheet, when I left it as Sheet 2 then the data appeared.

Comment: Thanks for closing the loop on your question.  However, it isn't really clear why that would be the solution (unless you have formulas referencing the name that weren't updated).